# Linux issues on setting a timer function

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a process with 2 children, 1 of the children is responsible to read questions (line by line from a file), output every question and reading the answer, and the other one is responsable to measure the time elapsed and notify the user at each past 1 minute about the remaining time. My problem is that i couldn't find any useful example of how i can make this set time function to work. Here is what i have tried so far. The problem is that it outputs the same elapsed time every time and never gets out from the loop.

```
#include<time.h>
#define T 600000

int main(){
  clock_t start, end;
  double elapsed;
  start = clock();
  end = start + T;
  while(clock() < end){
     elapsed = (double) (end - clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     printf("you have %f seconds left\n", elapsed);
     sleep(60);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it outputs the same elapsed time every time and never get's out of that while

Comment: If you only need second level resolution, use time()

Comment: `clock` measures processor time.  You want something that uses wall time.  Possibilities: `alarm`, `sleep`, `nanosleep`, `setitimer`, `timer_create`, `select` with timeout, `timerfd`, etc.

Comment: You **must read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)**

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Write an answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you should **read the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man page**.

Notice that [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) measure *processor* time, not *real* time.
I suggest using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` (or perhaps `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`). See also [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).
Also [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), the Linux specific [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc... Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

If you dare use signals, read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). But `timerfd_create` and `poll` should probably be enough to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simple that seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TIME    300

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i=TIME; i > 0; i--)
    {
            printf("You have [%d] minutes left.\n", i/60);
            sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Give it a try.